# How do I change certain plugins under Eclipse 3.6 product export to deploy as exploded Jars?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, export, osgi, product

I am using Eclipse 3.6 product export to build an Equinox-based OSGi application. I would like to be able to configure some of my plugins to deploy exploded instead of as JARs.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that if you are using a feature to wrap your plug-ins. The fragment.xml editor has an option for that:
[image]

Comment: Is that the only way to do that?

Comment: This is what I eventually had to do, after refitting our product exports to use features not plugins.